# Redirect to Magento admin dashboard

Tags: magento

I've scoured the internet looking for an answer to this, but have found nothing.  I have a custom extension. One of the functions will redirect the user to the admin dashboard.  How can this be done?

I've tried things like

```
$this->_redirect("/")
$this->_redirect("*")
$this->_redirect("*/*")
```

but nothing works.

Comment: A workaround for my specific situation,  where the redirect will only occur when someone initially goes to my extension, is to redirect to the referer, using $this->_redirectReferer();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a controller action, you can use the following:

```
<?php $this->_redirect('adminhtml/dashboard') ?>
```

If you're in an Adminhtml controller action, you can use:

```
<?php echo $this->_redirect('*/dashboard') ?>
```

This works as Adminhtml is the current module.

Answer (score 2):

at the end of your controller do:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('/'));
```

But this is just what runs through my mind...there are for sure several other ways to achieve this. Like always...